# Why Date() returns wrong date?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript2.2

I have the following function:

```
public static addDaysNextPrev(operation: number, date: Date = new Date(), days: number = 7): IDateCalendarNextPrev {
    const currentDate = new Date(date);
    const prevDate = new Date(date);

    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + (days * operation));
    prevDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - (days * operation));
    console.log(prevDate);

}
```

I try to add/minus some days from current date. Idea is to add 7 days to current date and return prev date and next.

Parameter `operation` is number `1` or positive or negative that determine direction to next date or to prev date.

I always get wrong date in line:

```
console.log(prevDate);
```

This is my second solution, more obviously:

```
public static addDaysNextPrev(operation: boolean, date: Date = new Date(), days: number = 7): IDateCalendarNextPrev {
    let currentDate = new Date(date);
    let prevDate = new Date(date);

    if (operation) {
      prevDate = date;
      currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + days);
    } else {
      currentDate.setDate(date.getDate() - days);
      prevDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - days);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're doing date work in JS, you really should be using [Moment](https://momentjs.com/). That said, it looks like you're adding 7 days to `currentDate`, then subtracting them again, leaving you at the original date.

Comment: Moment.js is handy but you don't need it for working with dates in JS. It would be a heavy dependency for something small like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding 7 days to `currentDate` at line:

```
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + (days * operation));
```

and subtracting 7 days of `currentDate` at the line:

```
prevDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - (days * operation));
```

So your `prevDate` will have the same value as `currentDate` initial value.

Correction here:

```
let operation = 1;
let date: Date = new Date();
let days: number = 7

const currentDate = new Date(date);
const prevDate = new Date(date);

prevDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - (days * operation));

console.log(prevDate);
```

Comment: Can you see my second solution, it work but sometime work wrong when going to prev dates

Comment: Whats is my mistake?

Comment: Lets say `days` value is 7 and `currentDate` is today.

If `operation` is true, `prevDate` will have the value of parameter `date` and `currentDate` will be 7 days ahead from today.

if `operation` is false, `currentDate` will have the value of 7 days before today and `prevDate` will be `currentDate` (that is already 7 days before today) and again minus 7 days.



Read your algorithm step by step if you don't know debugging with Chrome.

Comment: When I pass date I see in console 1 May in parameter `dt`, below when I do `let prevDate = new Date(dt); `it display me 17 May instead 1 May. Why different date?

Comment: I am using 17 May in this JSBin: https://jsbin.com/padahevevo/edit?js,console

click on Run button top right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169184/discussion-between-dooglu-and-cassiano-montanari).

Comment: @dooglu If your problem is solved please accept the answer

Comment: If it worked on jsbin, you should debug your code before calling that function then.